# ReactJS - map doesn't work for single item

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a really trivial problem with `map` function. I am making a request to my API, which returns the single object. I then want to display the object in render method.

```
const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: `https://localhost:5001/api/v1/`
})

class SinglePost extends Component {
    state = {
        post: []
    }
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        api.get(`posts/9a6b5be6-b3ef-4c2d-a36b-08da14c62914`).then(res => {
            console.log(res.data)
            this.setState({ posts: res.data })
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    this.state.post.map(x => <h2>{x.title}</h2>)
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SinglePost;
```

The `console.log()` of res.data seems to display the data just fine.

```
{
    "id": "9a6b5be6-b3ef-4c2d-a36b-08da14c62914",
    "name": null,
    "title": "Teeest",
    "urlTitle": null,
    "content": "123",
    "created": "2022-04-02T18:30:55.1536762",
    "description": "123",
    "score": 0,
    "isDeleted": false,
    "currentFlagStatus": 0,
    "flagReason": null,
    "userId": "9ecac069-8cfc-4cac-8056-87093fb9c57c",
    "authorName": null,
    "authorProfilePic": null,
    "hashtags": [
        {
            "id": "a8bc782c-7f5e-4dfc-220c-08da1355d3ec",
            "hashtagName": "byq",
            "hashtagNameInLower": "byq",
            "amountOfHashtagFollowers": 0
        },
        {
            "id": "a5efd6b1-cff0-40b5-2218-08da1355d3ec",
            "hashtagName": "Test",
            "hashtagNameInLower": "test",
            "amountOfHashtagFollowers": 0
        }
    ],
    "comments": []
}
```

However my `map` function doesn't seem to put the data inside the `<h2>` tag. Setting the breakpoint exactly at `this.state.post.map(x => <h2>{x.title}</h2>)` showed that it's not even being hit, however there are no errors on the console. How can I properly map this?

EDIT:

Just like Alon Barenboim and Nicholas Tower pointed out, there was a typo (setting state to posts instead of post). However, the issue now is that that piece of code now throws the error that `this.state.post.map is not a function`.

Comment: You're sometimes interacting with `post` singular, and sometimes `posts` plural. You'll need to make it consistent.

Comment: That's right. It was a small typo. However now, I get the error that `this.state.post.map is not a function`. Any ideas of why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the issue is that you call `this.setState({ posts: res.data })` for `posts`, but trying to map `post`:  `this.state.post.map(x => <h2>{x.title}</h2>`

EDIT:

If I understand correctly, you just need to display the data that is stored inside the `posts` object in a component.
In order to do so, you can just do the following:

```
const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: `https://localhost:5001/api/v1/`
})

class SinglePost extends Component {
    state = {
        posts: []
    }
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        api.get(`posts/9a6b5be6-b3ef-4c2d-a36b-08da14c62914`).then(res => {
            console.log(res.data)
            this.setState({ posts: res.data })
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.posts ? <h2>this.state.posts.title</h2> : null}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SinglePost;
```

You can obtain each value that is stored inside the state object just by writing `{this.state.posts.ATTRIBUTE}`

Comment: Thank you, you're totally right. However, now I get the error that `this.state.post.map is not a function`. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: This error comes up because apparently `res.data` does not contain an array, and so it does not have a map function. Based on the log that you brought, it's an object.

Comment: So how can I map it to the component?

Comment: To be more clear, you can iterate through object data, but you need to do it manually. If you need help to find the way, please post an extended log of a response from inside `res.data`, and I'll try to help.

Comment: I edited the question so it does containg the full log. I tried doing it manually by JSON.parse(this.state.post) but throws the error that it has unexpected end of JSON file.

Comment: @CheWatt98 I edited my answer with a possible solution, If I understood correctly. Let me know if it will do.

Comment: I want to buy you a huge bouquet of roses right now. I was trying to do this in million of ways and it was that simple. Thank you so much, it works!